Error with ES Modules in Next.js Project initialization
I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js project related to ES modules. Here’s the error message
Error Message:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /path/to/file.js



Context:

I'm using Next.js version 14.2.4.
My project setup includes React 18 and React-DOM 18.
I'm running Node.js version 22.3.0

Steps I've Taken:

I added "type": "module" to my package.json.
I ensured that my JavaScript files have the .mjs extension or are correctly recognized as ES modules.
I’m using import statements like import Image from 'next/image';.

package.json:
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.4"
  }
}

Despite these steps, the error persists. It seems to be an issue with how Node.js and Next.js handle ES modules.
Questions:

Is there a specific configuration or setup required to make ES modules work seamlessly with Next.js?
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?
Are there any compatibility issues between Next.js 14.2.4 and the Node.js version I'm using that could be causing this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
